# Testing Oracle DB table structure with Spring-Java

Tags: java, sql, database, spring, oracle

Im connecting to an external database wich im not able to populate with testdata to do a proper integration test suite for my DAO on. As an alternative I would like to test the structure of the tables. For example that the tables im using has columns with certain names and types. How is this possible with Java/Spring?

In Oracle SQL Developer I can use `desc <tableName>;` to get what I want, is there someting smilar i can do from Spring?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html), see [here](https://github.com/uklance/tader/blob/master/tader-core/src/main/java/org/tader/jdbc/JdbcEntitySchema.java) for some inspiration (and test case [here](https://github.com/uklance/tader/blob/master/tader-core/src/test/java/org/tader/jdbc/JdbcEntitySchemaTest.java))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dbms_metadata package(unless you're on XE release). This will either return DDL for a database object either as SQL script or as XML formatted string.

It's a way how SQLDeveloper reverse engineers object definitions.
AFAIK you have to use database dependent approach for this.